# Python2 extracting tags from xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have xml document that I need to parse, but I am stuck, I may say at the very beggining.
Here is part of xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I want to print out element tags only. I do it with this piece of code form python docs.
I issue these commands at python interpreter.

```
tree = ET.parse('pom.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root = ET.fromstring(data)
root.tag
```

root.tag returns this

```
{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project
```

Is expected result just

```
project
```

?

Comment: i didn't find any closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is parsing your XML in a way that keeps the declared namespaces and thus does not lose data, so the expected result is not just `project` :)

The `{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project` you see is a namespace-qualified name for the tag.

Even if the tag start `<project` does not contain a namespace prefix, the immediately following `xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` attribute declares every tag that has no explicit namespace prefix to belong into that namespace.

If you absolutely want a non-namespace-qualified name, you can of course do `tag_name = element.tag.split("}", 1)[-1]`. (This should be safe for non-namespace-qualified names due to the `-1` indexing.)

And of course you can recursively walk an ElementTree tree and replace all `tag.name`s with their non-namespace-qualified names with the above expression if you really really want to.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is complete and your understanding of my question is perfect. Although I could ask it better.